# ActiveMQ Cached LDAP admin can't read advisory

Tags: activemq-classic, openldap

I'm configuring an activeMQ with cached LDAP authentication.

For the moment, there's an user "cta" that send messages (IoT) to topics and an admin "itopsystem" that read from those topics (App)

the user cta is in a group "users" that has read, write rights to the topics, and itopsystem is in admins group. it works fine for the cta user but with itopsystem i have this error :

> Security Error occurred on connection to: tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:47704, User itopsystem is not authorized to read from: ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection,ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.app/CTA/>,ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Topic.app/CTA/>,app/motronics/>,app/motronics/#, app/ethairbox/>,app/ethairbox/#,ethairbox/>,ethairbox/#, | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///xx.xx.xx.xx:47704@61616

There's my ldap architecture

[image]

XML config

```
<authorizationPlugin>
<map>
<cachedLDAPAuthorizationMap connectionURL="ldap://localhost:389" connectionUsername="cn=Manager,dc=app,dc=com" connectionPassword="xxxxxxx" queueSearchBase="ou=Queue,ou=Destination,ou=ActiveMQ,dc=activemq,dc=app,dc=com" topicSearchBase="ou=Topic,ou=Destination,ou=ActiveMQ,dc=activemq,dc=app,dc=com" tempSearchBase="ou=Temp,ou=Destination,ou=ActiveMQ,dc=activemq,dc=app,dc=com" refreshInterval="300000" legacyGroupMapping="false"/>
</map>
</authorizationPlugin>
```

Why is my itopsystem user lack of rights if he's in the admins group ? The members are set like that in the group branch: member: uid=itopsystem